# Change the password using Microsoft graph API: "code:"Request_BadRequest" - message:"An error occurred while processing the change password request.""

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, chatbot

I am trying to change my office account password using Microsoft graph API in a chatbot application. I added the permission: *Directory.AccessAsUser.All* and I am logging in successfully.

Here is my request:

[image]

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Which type of application permission do you use? Delegated or application permission type?

Comment: It is Delegated (work or school account)

Comment: According to the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1), the response should be **204 no content**, so if you can remove the responseType and ResultProperty in your request? I called the api successfully, so I think there may be some differences between your request and mine. See my test below.

Answer (score 0):

I test it and got success, so if you can remove the `responseType` and `ResultProperty` in your request? And I saw you have 2 content type setting, if you can remove the second one which is `contentType`?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am calling the API from bot composer so the ResultProperty is just a property to save the response in and then I can see where it returned 204 or not. And the responseType is the type of the response which is JSON so also it doesn't matter. Anyways I tried removing them but still did not work :/ Please can you send me the link to where did you test it?

Comment: @SaraShreim Thanks for your reply sir, and I just used tools from chrome browser plugin, you can also try postman. And I think you can then trying to get the access token and use the token to call the api and test if the token worked. If not, I think you need to find out how to generate correct access token then.

Comment: Yes it is working with the api on any operation but the change password. Anyways thank you!

Comment: @SaraShreim if you can try to decode the access token you used to change the password and provide the `scp` claim here? It should contain "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"